# No result when using search analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search string using `query_string` in elasticsearch with accented characters.

When I use `query_string` without analyzer for query I get result only on exact match (I'm searching for string "Ředitel kvality" so When I dot "Reditel kvality" I get no results)

When I use same analyzer as it's used in mappings I get no results with both string with or without ascended characters.

analyzers & filters:

```
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "cs_CZ": {
          "recursion_level": "0",
          "locale": "cs_CZ",
          "type": "hunspell",
          "dedup": "true"
        },
        "czech_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "czech"
        },
        "czech_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_czech_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "cz": {
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "czech_stop",
            "icu_folding",
            "cs_CZ",
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        },
        "folding": {
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
```

mappings:

```
"index1": {
    "mappings": {
      "type1": {
        "properties": {
          "revisions": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "boost": 10.0,
                "fields": {
                  "folded": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "boost": 6.0,
                    "analyzer": "folding"
                  }
                },
                "analyzer": "cz"
```

here are term vectors which looks fine:

```
"term_vectors": {
        "revisions.title": {
          "field_statistics": {
            "sum_doc_freq": 764,
            "doc_count": 201,
            "sum_ttf": 770
          },
          "terms": {
            "kvalita": {
              "term_freq": 1,
              "tokens": [
                {
                  "position": 1,
                  "start_offset": 8,
                  "end_offset": 15
                }
              ]
            },
            "reditel": {
              "term_freq": 1,
              "tokens": [
                {
                  "position": 0,
                  "start_offset": 0,
                  "end_offset": 7
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

and when I run analyze on my query `index1/_analyze?field=type1.revisions.title&text=Ředitel%20kvality`
I get same tokens.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "reditel",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "kvalita",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I can't find out what is wrong and why ES will not match "Reditel kvality" with "Ředitel kvality".

this is query which I'm using:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "query":"\u0158editel kvality*",
                  "rewrite":"scoring_boolean",
                  "analyzer":"cz",
                  "default_operator":"AND"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":10,
   "from":0
}
```

my ES version is 5.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what's wrong.
`_all` field must be defined also in mappings with analyzer. 
I get from docs feeling that this is automatic, and all field is magically created from analyzed fields.

so now in fields I have

```
_all": {
          "enabled": true,
          "analyzer": "cz"
        },
```

And it's working.

Thank's a lot **Xylakant** on IRC for guiding me.